# Finding all functions $f(x)$ so that $f'(x)\sin x - f(x)\cos x = \sin^2x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f(x)$, so that $f'(x)\sin x - f(x)\cos x = \sin^2x$.

Note: I should solve it without using differential equations.
I've been trying to write the LHS as a derivative of some function but no success. I would like some hints.

Comment: Without using differential equations? This *is* a differential equation! ;)

Comment: Do you mean to say you are supposed to express some of the terms as a derivative of something?

Comment: A hint: The LHS is of the form $(y')(\sin x)-(y)(\cos x)$. Were it $+$ instead of $-$, it would be more obvious. Where would you find *this* form?

Comment: Oh you didn't catch me. Your idea *is* correct. I am saying there *is* a form, where a '$-$' appears instead of the $+$. Try to find it!

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I think I just found it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many such questions can be easily solved if you observe that one of the sides of the equation can be expressed in some standard form. One such form is $f\cdot g' - g\cdot f'$. This can be written as:
$$ \dfrac{g\cdot f' - f\cdot g'}{g^2}$$
or $$-\dfrac{f\cdot g' - g\cdot f'}{f^2} $$
Both forms can be useful at various times! In your problem, $f=f(x)$ and $g=\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...If you divide by $\sin^2 x$ you have an exact derivative

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{\sin x}\right)'=1$$